# Jenkins inside docker on windows 10 pro. Build failing - docker-compose not found

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I am trying to setup Jenkins inside docker on Windows 10 pro.
I have a python app that successfully runs on powershell command.
However, when I run the following command on build execute shell on Jenkins,

docker-compose run app sh -c python manage.py test && flake8

I keep getting the error

> /tmp/jenkins7355151386125740055.sh: 2:
>   /tmp/jenkins7355151386125740055.sh: docker-compose: not found Build
>   step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

What all I tried:

1. installed docker-compose using pip install docker-compose
2. set the path of docker-compose in the environment-path variable
3. created a .env file in the same directory as docker-compose.yml and included the following variable in it
          `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`
4. My `docker-compose.yml` is this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -C "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Can anyone help me figure out where am I going wrong and how could I fix the docker-compose not found error?

Answer (score 0):

add env file path to docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    env_file:
     - {PATH/TO/ENV_FILE}
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -C "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Also if you're building in a container in Jenkins, make sure you have docker-compose setup on Jenkins server (should be a plug-in)

You can try running this at the beginning of your shell script in Jenkins.

```
curl -L --fail https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I did every thing that I could think of to make this work. Unfortunately I still get the error docker-compose not found. I did go into jenkins workspace and tried docker-compose from the terminal and it works fine. When I type any docker-compose command on the jenkins-shell I keep getting the  docker-compose not found error. I set the path to docker-compose on /etc/environment, set privileges&permissions right on docker-compose to get recognized. I still have the same problem :(